# Multithread & multiprocess map

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```py
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from copy import deepcopy

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-np.sum(x)))

def layer(inputs, weights):
    biasedInputs = np.append(np.array(inputs), 1)
    neuronInputs = np.repeat(np.array([biasedInputs]), len(weights), axis = 0)
    weightedInputs = neuronInputs * np.array(weights)
    
    out = list(map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))

    return np.array(out)
```

How can I make `out = list(map(sigmoid, weightedInputs))` multithreaded or multiprocessed? `weightedInputs` are 3-d arrays. All the methods I tried made the code run slower.

Comment: Multithreading won't help because it's CPU-bound work, if this is CPython. Probably use MP and `map`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html. As an aside, I see you have a `deepcopy` import. That function is super inefficient so be careful where you're using it.

Comment: For many operations `numpy` uses multiprocessing internally and it is self-defeating for *you* to be using multiprocessing on top of it. Don't be surprised if multiprocessing does not improve performance (or even worsens it). I can't give you code since this is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).